# What is the Reset time for rate limt on Twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, rate-limiting

My appllication uses twitter api to post DM. I want to keep a track of the DM's so that i don't exceed the rate limit(1000 DM per-user/per-app). I want to know what time does the twitter resets the count for rate limit so that I can sync it with my application's count if i don't exceed the rate limit for that day.Is the DM rate limit also distributed over the entire day in slots of 15min window as others? If yes what is the distribution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is a 15 minute window. If you exceed a particular rate limit, you must wait 15 minutes for the limit to be reset. However, for posting tweets it's a little different. There is no published rate limit or window. This is to deflect spammers. When you get a 403 error, your best bet is to keep trying at some not-too-short interval until the post succeeds.